# Qt QDataWidgetMapper not mapping to widget

Tags: qt

I am having a hard time mapping a model to a widget in Qt. The relevant code is as follows:

header file declarations:

```
Ui::Widget *ui;
QStringList list;
QStringListModel *model;
QDataWidgetMapper *mapper;
```

cpp file implementation (in the constructor):

```
ui->setupUi(this); //only creates a QComboBox called comboBox
model = new QStringListModel(this);
mapper = new QDataWidgetMapper(this);
list << "Item 1" << "Item 2" << "Item 3";
model->setStringList(list);
mapper->setModel(model);
mapper->addMapping(ui->comboBox, 0);
mapper->toFirst();
```

For some reason the comboBox is not populated with the items in the QStringList list. Please help and tell me what I am doing wrong! Not using the mapper at all works fine (supplying the model directly to the widget), but there is a learning aspect to this as well, so please don't suggest not to use the mapper.

Your time and efforts are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QComboBox` can't be mapped directly with `QDataWidgetMapper`. You need to use a separate model for it. Check out [Combo Widget Mapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/itemviews-combowidgetmapper.html) example on how to do it.

Or do you just want to drive a combo box with a model? That's not what `QDataWidgetMapper` is for. Use [`QComboBox::setModel()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#setModel) for that.